# Fourier Transform of a Piecewise Function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm trying to do the Fourier Transform of the function below

[image]

Where R is just a constant, and I would like to transform from x into k space and here is my code:

```
FourierTransform[{3/(4 \[Pi]R^3), x <= R}, {0, x > R}, x, k]
```

However, I can not get right answer as expressed in the literature, the correct expression is as follows:

[image]

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at `Piecewise` and `UnitStep`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
FourierTransform[Which[ x <= R, 3/(4 \[Pi] R^3), True, 0], x, k]// Simplify[#, R > 0] & ;
% //ExpToTrig
(*-((3 I Cos[k R])/(4 Sqrt[2] k \[Pi]^(3/2) R^3)) + (3 Sin[k R])/(4 Sqrt[2] k \[Pi]^(3/2) R^3)*)
```

[image]